# Clearing frames in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, frame, python-3.3

Without any formal training and a very basic understanding of Python 3.3, I am trying really hard to understand tkinter to make a basic gui. I have read up on this method:

[Tkinter! Understanding how to switch frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301300/tkinter-understanding-how-to-switch-frames)

which is way over my head. I don't learn very well from copying and pasting code. My question is this:

If I want to make a gui with multiple windows, which I achieve by simply destroying a frame and replacing it with another while using a class, I guess I just don't understand why it's so darn difficult. I played around for a while today and I don't understand why the following code doesn't work. What I cannot wrap my noodle around is **why does it flip to the new window properly, but fails to return to the main window.** Both buttons are coded identically for their respective purposes, yet one works and one doesn't.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.new_switch_on = False
        self.main_switch_on = False
        self.main_frame()

    def main_frame(self):
        if self.new_switch_on == True:
            self.new_frame.destroy()
        self.new_switch_on = False
        self.main_switch_on = True
        self.main_frame = Frame(self.master, width = 200, height = 100)
        Label(self.main_frame, text = 'Main Frame').pack()
        Button(self.main_frame, text = 'Next', command = self.new_frame).pack()
        self.main_frame.pack()

    def new_frame(self):
        if self.main_switch_on == True:
            self.main_frame.destroy()
        self.main_switch_on = False
        self.new_switch_on = True
        self.new_frame = Frame(self.master, width = 400, height = 200)
        Label(self.new_frame, text = 'New Frame').pack()
        Button(self.new_frame, text = 'Back', command = self.main_frame).pack()
        self.new_frame.pack()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('-1+1')

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I know I can follow the aforementioned link to get the desired result, but I just don't understand why something like this, or something else that is a bit more simplistic for a new learner couldn't accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because you use the same name for method `main_frame(self, ...)` and for frame `self.main_frame = Frame(...)`.

When you assign frame to variable `self.main_frame = Frame(...)` then you loose access to method `self.main_frame()` and your `Button(self.new_frame, text = 'Back', command=self.main_frame)` can't call method `self.main_frame`.

Use different name for method `main_frame` - for example `create_main_frame`

The same problem is with `new_frame(self, ...)` and `self.new_frame = Frame(...)`

(ps. I add to code empty lines to make it more readable)

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.new_switch_on = False
        self.main_switch_on = False

        self.create_main_frame()

    def create_main_frame(self): # new name
        if self.new_switch_on == True:
            self.new_frame.destroy()

        self.new_switch_on = False
        self.main_switch_on = True

        self.main_frame = Frame(self.master, width = 200, height = 100)

        Label(self.main_frame, text = 'Main Frame').pack()
        Button(self.main_frame, text = 'Next', command = self.create_new_frame).pack()  # new name

        self.main_frame.pack()

    def create_new_frame(self): # new name
        if self.main_switch_on == True:
            self.main_frame.destroy()

        self.main_switch_on = False
        self.new_switch_on = True

        self.new_frame = Frame(self.master, width = 400, height = 200)

        Label(self.new_frame, text='New Frame').pack()
        Button(self.new_frame, text='Back', command=self.create_main_frame).pack()  # new name

        self.new_frame.pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('-1+1')

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yep...I feel like an idiot especially since I know better than to do that. Thanks for pointing it out though. Works exactly as intended and now after eliminating the Booleans and changing a couple of things, it still works perfectly.