# About self.controller = controller . Does controller always mean the main program?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have read from here([Tkinter! Understanding how to switch frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301300/tkinter-understanding-how-to-switch-frames)) about self.controller = controller. I'm only new to python and also to tkinter, I just want to ask if the 'controller' does always refer to the main program? If not, Can you please give an example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the controller does not always refer to the main program. It can refer to any object you want. In the example you cite, using the application was the simplest, shortest solution.

For example:

```
class Model(...): ...
class Controller(...): ...
class View(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        ...
    ...
class App(...):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        model = Model(...)
        controller = Controller(..., model=self.model)
        view = View(..., controller=self.controller)
        controller.add_view(view)
        ...
    ,,,

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Comment: Im still confused.If not always the main program, how does python know what "self.controller = controller" is referring to? How does python know that its another object,not the main program?

Comment: @marcoalexis: how does python know? You tell it. If you pass in some other object, `self.controller` is set to that object. You can pass whatever you want into the parameter for `controller`

Comment: about the code that I have cited, I think thats originally from you?The self.controller = controller directly refers to the main program even though It is not defined in the main program because  one else can be referred to right? and to your other examples in your answer a while ago, It can refer to any other objects because there are many classes declared and you specifically set it to a particular object, right?

Comment: @marcoalexis: stackoverflow isn't designed for extended discussions. I can't answer those questions in a comment field.